# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path but natives are set

Tags: java, lwjgl

I understand that this question has been asked before, yet no matter how many solutions I try, I still get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Game" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:97)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.<clinit>(Library.java:48)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryAccess.<clinit>(MemoryAccess.java:22)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Pointer.<clinit>(Pointer.java:22)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.<clinit>(GLFW.java:594)
    at Main.init(Main.java:27)
    at Main.run(Main.java:39)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The problem is that I have properly set my Natives:
[image: Properties Dialog]

This is the location folder:

[image]

I have just downloaded LWJGL and would like help in order to make it work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking at the files list above there is no lwjgl.dll in the folder. Could you make a copy of lwjgl32.dll as lwjgl.dll and see if that helps. If not what is the value of java.library.path?

Comment: @AndreM That returned this: Exception in thread "Game" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\users\p\lwjgl\native\lwjgl.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
 at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)                 However, I cannot find a 64 bit version of LWJGL 3

Comment: @AndreM It turns out that my anti-virus was deleting the .dll files that i needed. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my anti-virus is deleting LWJGL.